# Google Analytics not working in web app

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

My GA Property page says "Tracking not installed", but looking at the execution on my Home page in the GA Debugger extension, it appears to be running. I waited two days based on reports that it can take a day to update the "Tracking not installed" message. (BTW, the page used to work with the "old" GA code, so I think that means that the basic GA setup is appropriate.) What should I try to make this work?

My home page looks like this:

```
...
    <!-- Google Analytics -->
    <script>
        (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
        (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
        m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
        })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

        ga('create', 'UA-36102872-1', 'auto');
        ga('send', 'pageview');
    </script>
    <!-- End Google Analytics -->

</head>
<body>
```

And output from the GA Chrome Debugger extension looks like this:

```
Initializing Google Analytics                             analytics_debug.js:9 
Running command: ga("create", "UA-36102872-1", "auto")    analytics_debug.js:9
Creating new tracker: t0                                  analytics_debug.js:9
Auto cookieDomain found: "laurenroyal.com"                analytics_debug.js:9
Running command: ga("send", "pageview")                   analytics_debug.js:9

Sent beacon:                                              analytics_debug.js:9
v=1&_v=j37d&a=110114195&t=pageview&_s=1&dl=http%3A%2F%2Flaurenroyal.com%2F3.0%2F&ul=en-us&de=UTF-8&dt=Lauren%20Royal&sd=24-bit&sr=1440x900&vp=1213x741&je=1&fl=17.0%20r0&_u=AACAAEABI~&jid=&cid=1356707842.1433635813&tid=UA-36102872-1&z=1120976129


_j1              (&jid)                                   analytics_debug.js:9 
adSenseId        (&a)   110114195                         analytics_debug.js:9 
apiVersion       (&v)   1                                 analytics_debug.js:9 
clientId         (&cid) 1356707842.1433635813             www.google-analytics.com/analytics_debug.js:9 
encoding         (&de)  UTF-8                             www.google-analytics.com/analytics_debug.js:9 
flashVersion     (&fl)  17.0 r0                           www.google-analytics.com/analytics_debug.js:9 
hitType          (&t)   pageview                          www.google-analytics.com/analytics_debug.js:9 
javaEnabled      (&je)  1                                 www.google-analytics.com/analytics_debug.js:9 
language         (&ul)  en-us                             www.google-analytics.com/analytics_debug.js:9 
location         (&dl)  http://laurenroyal.com/3.0/       www.google-analytics.com/analytics_debug.js:9 
screenColors     (&sd)  24-bit                            www.google-analytics.com/analytics_debug.js:9 
screenResolution (&sr)  1440x900                          www.google-analytics.com/analytics_debug.js:9 
title            (&dt)  Lauren Royal                      www.google-analytics.com/analytics_debug.js:9 
trackingId       (&tid) UA-36102872-1                     www.google-analytics.com/analytics_debug.js:9 
viewportSize     (&vp)  1213x741                          www.google-analytics.com/analytics_debug.js:9
```

Comment: Are you seeing anything in Real-Time reports? I would assume so as the data you posted looks good. Also make sure you are not blocking your own visits. Is your site built from a CMS of some sort, and are you including the GA snippet through a plugin?

Comment: Nothing in the real-time reports. Site is not CMS-based, it's a LAMP-based app; the GA snippet is in a base file that is included in every page. The code snippet above was obtained from "View Source" in my browser. Tested with Safari, Firefox, and Chrome (the debugger output, of course, was from Chrome). It's either something simple that I'm missing, or something very subtle.

Comment: Your data is sent correctly and GA returns 200 ok and the tracking pixel, so the problem is not data collection. Did you perhaps create any filters on your data view ? (The "tracking not installed" message seems to be useless btw., I have that popping up in a few accounts that show data without problems).

Comment: No filters, and no data. Appreciate the heads-up about ignoring the "Tracking not installed" message.